# How to set multiple textviews with ellipsize only on some of them

Tags: android, layout

I have a little complicated layout I want to make in my `ListView` adpater.

Each item in the list is combined of 4 `TextView`

The first three `TextView` are basically one sentence, but I want the second `TextView` not to be ellipsized, and the first and the third I do want to be ellipsized.

The last `TextView` is need to be positioned to the right side.

so if the all the first three `TextView` can't be shown completely, the layout should be like this:

```
`TextView1...` `TextView2` `TextView3...`  `TextView4`
```

My code is working in this case, but in simple case when no ellipsize is necessary, it doesn't and it looks like this:

```
`TextView1`       `TextView2` `TextView3`  `TextView4`
```

Here's my code:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(m_context);
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
layout.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


LinearLayout textLayout = new LinearLayout(m_context);
textLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
textLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

view.m_text1 = new TQTextView(m_context);
view.m_text1.setSingleLine();
view.m_text1.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);

view.m_text2 = new TQTextView(m_context);

view.m_text3 = new TQTextView(m_context);
view.m_text3.setSingleLine();
view.m_text3.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);

view.m_text1 = new TQTextView(m_context);

textLayout.setWeightSum(2f);
textLayout.addView(view.m_text1, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
textLayout.addView(view.m_text2, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0f));
textLayout.addView(view.m_text3, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

layout.addView(textLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));


view.m_text4 = new TQTextView(m_context);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0f);
int margin = 10;
params.leftMargin = margin;
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.RIGHT;

layout.addView(view.m_text4, params);
```

Comment: Eh, add '...' to the sentence?

Comment: In your code `m_text4` isn't added to a view and `m_text2` is added with different layout parameters for no obvious reason

Comment: Why not create this layout in xml and inflate it in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

I add the three `TextView` without special `LayoutParams` like this:

```
textLayout.addView(view.m_attackeeName);
textLayout.addView(view.m_text);
textLayout.addView(view.m_attackerName);
```

and I call the following function in the end of `getView` function (after setting the texts)

```
private void updateTexts(View parent, ViewHolder view, Data data){
    view.m_text1.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    view.m_text3.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    view.m_text2.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    view.m_text4.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int totalWidth = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingLeft() - parent.getPaddingRight();
    totalWidth = totalWidth - view.m_text4.getMeasuredWidth() - view.m_text2.getMeasuredWidth() - m_margin;

    int attackerTextWidth = view.m_text1.getMeasuredWidth();
    int attackeeTextWidth = view.m_text3.getMeasuredWidth();
    if( attackerTextWidth + attackeeTextWidth > totalWidth )
    {
        int spareWidth = totalWidth / 2 - attackerTextWidth;
        if( spareWidth > 0 )
        {
            attackeeTextWidth = totalWidth / 2 + spareWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            spareWidth = totalWidth / 2 - attackeeTextWidth;
            if( spareWidth > 0 )
            {
                attackerTextWidth = totalWidth / 2 + spareWidth;
            }
            else
            {
                attackerTextWidth = totalWidth / 2;
                attackeeTextWidth = totalWidth / 2;
            }
        }
    }

    String text = TextUtils.ellipsize(data.GetText1(), view.m_text1.getPaint(),
            attackerTextWidth, TextUtils.TruncateAt.END).toString();
    view.m_text1.setText(text);
    text = TextUtils.ellipsize(data.GetText3(), view.m_text3.getPaint(),
            attackeeTextWidth, TextUtils.TruncateAt.END).toString();
    view.m_text3.setText(text);
}
```